# how to set src to relativeLayout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation

I have 2 images: `bg_Image`, `box_image`

I want to use `bg_Image` to be the background.

I have used android RelativeLayout, but when I set it to be the background - it spans too much.

I want it to keep the original `bg_Image` size. I couldn't set the RelativeLayout `src` to be the `bg_Image`.

another thing is the `box_image` be a child of `bg_Image`

as I want to use animation to move `box_image` relative to its parent size

that's why i want them to be in parent-child relation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
    <translate
 android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
     android:toXDelta="0%"
     android:duration="600">

    </translate>
</set>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set relative layout height and width to wrap content and than set the background to it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="your background image">
</Relativelayout>
```

or give fix height and width to relative layout.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height to wrap content.Setting to wrap content takes the original size of the image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_Image">

    </Relativelayout>
```

Hope this would help..:)